# winsock bind cannot be converted to int

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, winsock, winsock2

I am having a strange error that I can't find anywhere online. I am attempting to open a socket and bind it so I can send a UDP packet. However, the when I try to check if the bind succeeds, it won't compile. From what I have read, bind() is supposed to return an int, but for some reason it is not doing it in my program.

```
SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
// handle errors
struct sockaddr_in local;
memset(&local, 0, sizeof(local));
local.sin_family = AF_INET;
local.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
local.sin_port = htons(0);
if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&local, sizeof(local)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    cout << "Binding error\n";
    return false;
}
return true;
```

My only guess is that bind() is getting overloaded somehow (Maybe another library that I have included)

Comment: What error are you getting exactly? Can you give us enough code to reproduce the error?

Comment: Maybe your own class?

Comment: No, I had checked for that. Zbynek's answer below helped me fix this issue. It was conflicting with a C++ standard function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be conflict with std::bind in C++. Try prepending global namespace:

```
 ::bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&local, sizeof(local))
```

Comment: That seemed to fix it. Thanks. Would you mind explaining why that worked?

Comment: @TaiwanTimmy : sure, with  using namespace std another function bind is imported. With :: you say you want to use the one from global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

The better solution is stop `using namespace std;` once and for all. It does you much more harm than good (taking into account, it does you no good whatsoever).